# Rows in data frame with duplicated values in certain columns

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose a data frame df has 5 columns a1 to a5. I want those rows of df which have common values in columns a1 and a2.

```
 col=c("a1","a2" )
 df1=df[,which(colnames(df)%in%col)]
 l=which(duplicated(df1)==TRUE)
 df2=df[l, ]
```

Now `df2` contains only duplicate rows. I want to add matching rows with duplicated values.

Sample

```
  a1=c(1:3,3,4)
  a2=c("a1","a2","a2","a2","a1")
  a3=c(1:5)
  df=data.frame(a1,a2,a3)
  df
   a1 a2 a3
 1  1 a1  1
 2  2 a2  2
 3  3 a2  3
 4  3 a2  4
 5  4 a1  5
  col1=c("a1","a2" )
  df1=df[,which(colnames(df)%in%col1)]
  l=which(duplicated(df1)==TRUE)
  df2=df[l, ]
  df2
   a1 a2 a3
 4  3 a2  4
```

But I want `df2` to be

```
   a1 a2 a3
 3  3 a2  3
 4  3 a2  4
```

One solution is to search in df.. but my df has around 10M rows.. so this solution is efficient

Comment: Please show a small example and expected output based on that

Comment: added in Q, Pl refer to Q once again

Comment: A similar question was posted recently `df[duplicated(df[1:2])|duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast=TRUE),]`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  Have you tried on a different sample.  It should work

Comment: @akrun yeah it is working.. thanks alot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try instead of

```
 l=which(duplicated(df1)==TRUE)
```

use

```
l=which(duplicated(df1) | duplicated(df1,fromLast = T))
```

that should work for you

Answer (score 0):

You might also try this `data.table` solution for speed.  I think using the keys might be faster, depending on your table size vs. the overhead of the keys:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(a1,a2,a3)

setkey(dt, a1, a2)

dups <- which(duplicated(dt))

dt[dt[dups, list(a1, a2)]]
```

**edit:** please see Arun's comment below for an expert `data.table` formulation

Comment: data.frames don't have keys.  you need to do something like `library(data.table); dt <- as.data.table(df)` to make it a `data.table`, which inherits the properties of `data.frame` but adds lots of good things like keys.

Comment: getting errorError in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) :   4 arguments passed to .Internal(nchar) which requires 3

Comment: for `setkeyv` you need one vector `cols` of column names.  I.e., `setkey(dt, c('a1','a2')`.  I used `setkey` in my example

Comment: IIUC I think this is slightly more straightforward: `setDT(df)[, if (.N > 1L) .SD, by=.(a1,a2)]`